# Remove all factorial variables with more than 50% NA

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a CSV file with headers. Some of the features (columns) are factorial, some are numerical.

For the factorial variables I have a lot of columns with a lot of NAs, e.g.:

```
Num1 Fact1 Num2 Fact2 Fact3
9889  Bla   23   BBxv  NA
NA    NA    456  BBxz  NA
NA   Abcd   3    BBxx  Jet
NA    NA    100  BBxy  NA
NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
```

I Want to remove all Factorial columns with more than 50% NAs in it.

e.g. the resulting data frame should be:

```
Num1 Num2 Fact2
9889  23   BBxv
NA    456  BBxz
NA    3    BBxx
NA    100  BBxy
NA    NA   NA
```

Moreover, Is there a way to also remove numerical columns with more than 50% NAs in it, in the SAME process?

e.g. after the cleanup the resulting data frame would be one that contains only `Num2` and `Fact2` columns.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: `dff[colMeans(is.na(dff)) <= 0.5]`; where `dff` is your data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dff[colMeans(is.na(dff)) <= 0.5]
```

Should get:

```
 Num2 Fact2
 23   BBxv 
 456  BBxz 
 3    BBxx 
 100  BBxy 
 NA   <NA>
```

#### Edit:

If you're looking to remove columns with more than 50% of zeros in the same process, give the following a try:

```
dff[colMeans(is.na(dff)) <= 0.5 & colMeans((dff == 0), na.rm = T) <= 0.5]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That did help. Thanks